# How to add an object to a Java List?

Tags: java, android, list, nullpointerexception

This might be an extremely stupid question, but I keep on getting a NullPointer.

In my Android app I've got a class called MyMetadata, and I want to fill a List using objects of this class. So I try to do so as follows:

```
List<MyMetadata> metadataList;
MyMetadata myMetadata = new MyMetadata("first string", "second string");
Log.i(this, myMetadata.toString());
metadataList.add(myMetadata);
```

The `Log.i()` displays a line saying `com.mycompany.model.MyMetadata@41af34301`, so it does exist. But when I try to add it to the list I get a NullPointerException.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have **not initialized your list**. So, without initializing if you are trying to work around with an object it will end you up in Null pointer exception.

Try to initialize your list..

```
metadataList = new ArrayList<MyMetadata>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because no space is allocated to the list and the add function is not able to find any pointer to the same.

Initialise the list before you use it and it will solve the issue:

```
metadatalist = new ArrayList '<'MyMetadata'>'();
```

Please remove the single quotes in the above code around '><'. Somehow it wasn't showing up in the post without them.

Answer (score 1):

Your `metadataList` list is still uninitialized and thus is `null` by default. You need to initialize it before adding any elements to it. That's the reason you get the NPE.

```
List<MyMetadata> metadataList; // uninitialized
...
metadataList.add(myMetadata); // adding an element to an uninitialized will throw a NPE
```

Initialize it like this

```
List<MyMetadata> metadataList = new ArrayList<>(); // initialized now, example
...
metadataList.add(myMetadata);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list is not initialized...

```
List<MyMetadata> metadataList = new ArrayList<Metadata>();
```

ArrayList is one of the implementation of List interface, you can also initialize it as LinkedList, Vectors etc..

For complete list read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 1):

This happened because you forgot to initialize List metadataList.
Initialize it with any List implemented class
Ex:
List metadataList=new ArrayList();

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

firstly you needed to create a collection by initializing your variable ( metadataList )with ArrayList or other as your requirement then you can use it

```
   List<MyMetadata> metadataList=ArrayList<MyMetadata>();
   MyMetadata myMetadata = new MyMetadata("first string", "second string");
   Log.i(this, myMetadata.toString());
   metadataList.add(myMetadata);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
metadataList.add(myMetadata);
```

The above line is throwing you a NPE, your above line looks like `null.add(myMetadata)`
before adding objects into a list you have to initialize your list something like this `metadataList = new ArrayList<MyMetadata>();` then you can do this  `metadataList.add(myMetadata);`